# How to integrate Google Play app purchasing to Angular app using Cordova?

Tags: angular, cordova, google-api, google-play

I developed an Angular app and converted it into an android app using Cordova and published in Google Play.

My app has premium and subscription features. How can I implement these in my Angular app to access whatever the Google Play interface to support this?

I found tutorials on how to convert an Angular app to Android but not anything how to integrate in-app purchases with Google Play. I am sure you guys have done this.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Cordova in app purchase plugin. I've had great success with; [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-purchase
```

The Android set up and usage can be seen here;

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/Setup-for-Android-Google-Play#setup-android-applications

The API and coding documentation is here;

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/api.md
https://purchase.cordova.fovea.cc/use-cases/subscription-android

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralpharoo. I went through this. But it does not have information on how I can introduce the required in-app purchase code into the angular code. https://purchase.cordova.fovea.cc/use-cases/non-consumable-android. Do I need to edit the java script generated when I run ng build . Just had a look at the generated java script but have no clue on how I can edit that generated code to embed the in-app purchase code. How did you actually do this. Please advise

Comment: I am also confused as to how to integrate this with angular. Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: @MichaelNorgren This depends on your stack and what tools you are using to compile this as an app. The above is a JavaScript library built for Cordova. To use it within Angular you would just write a service to wrap the API and call the JavaScript methods from your Angular code (which is JS once compiled).

Comment: Thank you @Ralpharoo - I managed to find RevenueCat which has great start-up documentation for Ionic which is what I need for my Angular + Ionic + Capacitor app. They also had the webhooks I needed to validate subscriptions with Apple + Google + Stripe. Of course, with anything that is simple, its not free :-)